# How can I use a script to change the static IP address?

Tags: networking

How do I change the IP address of an interface from a script?

I should say that I don't want to use ifconfig and also I don't want to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file manually. I need a script.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `ifup` to configure the interface then you can define multiple so-called logical interface definitions for the interface and switch among them using ifup and ifdown. For example, you can define "iface home" and "iface work" in /etc/network/interfaces and then bring up eth0 either with "ifup eth0=home" or "ifup eth0=eth0-work". See ifup(8). Example of doing this from a script follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0=home
```

If you are using NetworkManager to configure the interface then you can define multiple so-called connections and switch between them using the `nmcli` command.

```
#!/bin/sh
nmcli con down id  'Wired connection work'
nmcli con up id  'Wired connection home'
```

If you are using neither ifupdown nor NetworkManager and you don't want to use ifconfig then you can use the `ip` utility. See ip(8).

```
#!/bin/sh
ip link set dev eth0 ...
```